# What does the onOpen status "failed" mean?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

In the [G Suite Developer Hub](https://script.google.com), under `My Projects > "insert project name here" > PROJECT DETAILS > Failed executions`, I keep seeing a status "failed" for the function `onOpen`.

My script uses `onOpen` to add menu items for the add-on, nothing complicated, so I'm sure that there is no problem with the code.

My hypothesis so far is that this error is being thrown during new installations but one of my users have reported any issues with it so far.
Has anyone else seen this error with their add-on?

**EDIT:**

```
function onOpen(e) {
var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createAddonMenu()
.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Heading 1")
.addItem("Item 1", "myFunction")
.addItem("Item 2", "myFunction1"))
.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Post your onOpen snippet here.

Comment: Done: code snippet added

Comment: [Review the authorization lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#the_complete_lifecycle).  Are you following those recommendations, like wrapping `onOpen` inside of `onInstall`?

Comment: Yes. I actually followed code Google had posted on GitHub when I first wrote this function so I'm safe on that front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Script Editor and run the onOpen function manually. This would grant the necessary authorization to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use createMenu instead of createAddonMenu:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu('Action Menu')
      .addItem('Execute my function', 'myfunction')
      .addToUi();

}
```

Comment: `onOpen(e)` does have an event object.  [See the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).  The OP isn't using it, but it does no harm to include it in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

### A possible reason for occurrence of "Failed" is that someone tries to run the script manually

with the "play" button (e.g. for testing purposes).
This will fail, given that there is no event `e` linked to the script execution.

But the script will still work as intended when it runs on trigger.